# newline separating word inside div

Tags: css, html, newline

Basically, i have two a tags in my div, and they are changeable. but if they are more than one word, or just words with more letters, i don't want them to get separated when new-line needed. i have this demo where i wrote down some of the possible outcomes. First div is what happens now which i want to prevent. http://jsfiddle.net/tVC43/1/

```
  <div class="box">
   welcome to <a>xxx</a> part.
  <a>hi thomas</a>
  </div>
  <div class="box" style="left:170px;">
   welcome to <a>xxx</a> part.
  <a style="display:block;">hi thomas</a>
  </div>
  <div class="box" style="left:340px;">
   welcome to <a>xxxxxxx</a> part.
  <a>hi thomas</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a no-break space instead of a normal space, e.g. `<a>hi&nbsp;thomas</a>`, or use the CSS setting `white-space: nowrap` on the element, or wrap content inside `<nobr>...</nobr>`.

Comment: thanks i used the <nobr> tag... my new problem is; i gave margin-left:5px, but when there is not a word in the left it doesnt look good in the newline.

Comment: @drake12, that sounds like a different question and should probably be asked separately, with a different title, and with your modified code posted.

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:block`

```
a:last-child, span:last-child{display:block}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tVC43/7/)**

Comment: thanks but, "hi thomas" is at a new line in your last div, i don't want that actually. the answer i was looking for is above.